# is there a power query in excel to transpose the rows into columns?

Tags: excel, powerbi, rows

I am looking for a way to transpose the rows into columns,
as an example, the data extracted are sorted as this way

[image]

and the output is should be similar to this

[image]

Every month, we've been doing it in a very long way and I believe that there must be a smarter way to do it using power query.
I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

The transformation you're looking for is called [Unpivot Columns](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098#:%7E:text=1%20To%20open%20a%20query%2C%20locate%20one%20previously,...%203%20Select%20Transform%20%3E%20Unpivot%20Other%20Columns.)

[image]